# How to pass data to Express router (and change url at the same time)

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, routes

So, Im developing this simple app that will basically contain 3 things:

1. authenticating using OAuth (google)
2. getting some data from other software based on
3. render data based on response from

So I'm having this router for the first thing:

```
# oauthcallback.js 
# I defined it in main app.js as:
# app.use('/oauthCallback', oauthCallbackRouter)

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const code = req.query.code
  const user = await getGoogleAccountFromCode(code)

  res.locals.user = user.email
  res.redirect('/devices')
});
```

and the second router for displaying actual data:

```
# devices.js 
# I defined it in main app.js as:
# app.use('/devices', devicesRouter)

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const freshServiceUserId = await fetchDevices(res.locals.user.email)

    res.render('devices', { devices });
});
```

But this solution won't work because locals seems to be cleared after a redirect. I could of course use `next()` instead of `res.redirect('/devices')`, and change router flow to `app.use('/oauthCallback', oauthCallbackRouter, devicesRouter)`
but this will keep 'not-so-nice' oauth url (which I'd like to change to /devices).

Is there some better way to navigate to new url after authenticating but without loosing data received during OAuth authentication? (I know I could use session... but Im not sure if thats correct way to solve this... I feel like theres a easier way... is there?)

Comment: You could use an encrypted(!) cookie to store the e-mail address in, but this is really exactly why sessions exist.

Comment: hmmm... thought there's better 'good pattern' for that, but yea, seems like session is a way to go, thanks :)